# handling data in objects and put all objects in ONE object , REACTJS

Tags: reactjs, forms, object, use-effect, use-state

when i submitting the form getting data in objects ==> all is OK,
after this I want to put all objects in ONE object but this happens after to clicking twice on submit form

Comment: Hey, can you provide a little more information? Code snippets of how you're handling the data and how you're trying to put all object in one might help. Also, it would be great if you could explain better what exactly happens after clicking twice on submit and what are these objects.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have a form and created a states the value of states by onChange method when submit the form, the value of states rendered on object(lets say this a small and i getting a lot of small objects)all small objects i want to set them on ONE object to send to firebase

Comment: i have 3 functions (function calc(),function renderCodes(), function renderForm()) All functions handleSubmit function

Comment: const handleSubmit=async(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        
        calc(total);
        renderCodes();
        renderForm()
        }

Comment: renderForm() depend on renderCodes()